# Getting the initial temperature

Tags: android

I am writing my first Android app and I am running into what I thought would be a simple issue.  I am trying to get the temperature of the device (using the 2.1 APIs).  I have followed [this example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

If the temperature changes, the app updates as expected. If the device is sitting on my desk, the temperature does not change and I never get an `onSensorChanged()` callback.

Although this sounds right (i.e. the sensor didn't change, so no update), I can't figure out how to get the current temperature when the app starts out.  I was hoping that `onSensorChanged()` would be called when the app starts, but that is not the case.

Is there some API I have missed?  I can't believe that there is no way to display the temperature until it changes.

Thank you.

Comment: Run some super CPU intensive algorithm. The temperature will definitely change and onSensorChanged will be called. :P

Comment: I am not sure my users would like that too much.  Sometimes I get an update immediately, but other times I get no call at all.  Interestingly enough, even though I asked to be notified no more than one time/second, I will sometimes get 30 or 40 calls in a row because the temperature is fluctuating between two values.  Not sure if these are bugs in the SDK / OS code or what.

Comment: With what I have seen with Android till now. The SDK/OS code doesn't behave in the way it's supposed to because the actual hardware interface is made by someone else. You need to try this out with different phones and see if it's a device issue or an OS issue. Pre 2.2 versions are almost obsolete you you can start off there.

Comment: Moving to 2.2 did not help. Great suggestion though.  Thanks.